# Maximum value of every contiguous subarray

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Given an unsorted array `A[0...n-1]` of integers and an integer `k`; the desired algorithm in C should calculate the maximum value of every contiguous subarray of size `k`. For instance, if `A = [8,5,10,7,9,4,15,12,90,13]` and `k=4`, then `findKMax(A,4,10)` returns `10 10 10 15 15 90 90`.

My goal is to implement the algorithm as a C programm that reads the elements of `A`, reads `k` and then prints the result of the function `findKMax(A,4,10)`. An input/output example is illustrated bellow (input is typeset in bold):

Elements of A: **8 5 10 7 9 4 15 12 90 13 end**

Type k: **4**

Results: 10 10 10 15 15 90 90

What I've tried so far? Please keep in mind that I am an absolute beginner in C. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findKMax(int A[], int k, int n) {

int j;
int max;

for (int i = 0; i <= n-k; i++) {
    max = A[i];

    for (j = 1; j < k; j++) {
        if (A[i+j] > max)
            max = A[i+j];
    }

}
}

int main() {

int n = sizeof(A);
int k = 4;

printf("Elements of A: ");
scanf("%d", &A[i]);
printf("Type k: %d", k);
printf("Results: %d", &max);

return 0;
}
```

**Update March 17th:**

I've modified the source code, i.e. I've tried to implement the hints of Michael Burr and Priyansh Goel. Here is my result:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Returning the largest value in subarray of size k.
void findKMax(int A[], int k, int n) {

int j;
int largestValueOfSubarray;

for (int i = 0; i <= n-k; i++) {
    largestValueOfSubarray = A[i];

    for (j = 1; j < k; j++) {
        if (A[i+j] > largestValueOfSubarray)
            largestValueOfSubarray = A[i+j];
    }
    printf("Type k: %d", k);

}
return largestValueOfSubarray;
}

int main() {

int n = 10;
int A[n];
// Reading values into array A.
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("Enter the %d-th element of the array A: \n", i);
    scanf("%d", &A[i]);
}

// Printing of all values of array A.
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\nA[%d] = %d", i, A[i]);
}

printf("\n\n");

// Returning the largest value in array A.
int largestValue = A[0];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (A[i] > largestValue) {
        largestValue = A[i];
    }
}
printf("The largest value in the array A is %d. \n", largestValue);

return 0;
}
```

I guess there is not so much to code. Can anybody give me a hint how to do the rest. I need an advice how to "combine" the pieces of code into a running program.

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: I use the XCode IDE and the code doesn't work.

Comment: ' code doesn't work' well, could you be slightly less vague?

Comment: What doesn't work? Does it compile? Does it run? BTW, I've understood the problem statement after reading it about 5 times...

Comment: Work in steps.  For example, first write a program that allows you to input an array and displays the contents of the array  Once that's working, add the capability of finding the max element of that array.  Then move to the next step of finding the max elements of the `k` sub arrays (hint: finding the max of a sub-array is really the same thing as finding the max of an array - the sub-array is just an array with a different starting point and a smaller number of elements).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are a beginner, lets begin with the simplest algorithm.

for every i, you need to find sum of k continous numbers starting from that i. And then find the max of it.

Before that you need to see how to take input to an array.

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);

int a[n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

Also, you will need to call the function `findKMax(a,n,k);`
In your findKMax function, you have to implement the algorithm that I mentioned.

I will not provide the code so that you may try on your own. If you face any issue, do tell me.

HINT : You need to use nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

You find max value in window many times, but output only the last max value.

The simplest correction - add output in the end of main cycle:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n-k; i++) {
    max = A[i];

    for (j = 1; j < k; j++) {
        if (A[i+j] > max)
            max = A[i+j];
    }
    printf("Type k: %d", k);
}
```

The next step - collect all local max values in a single string `"10 10 10 15 15 90 90"` or additional array of length `n-k+1: [10,10,10,15,15,90,90]` and print it after the main cycle (I don't know the best approach for this in C)